# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined and require

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, ecmascript-6

I'm using angularjs and typescript to create some app, I'm having a trouble with this error that I can't solve

Here is my *.ts code

```
export var NgApp = new application.Startup();

///<reference path="../../../../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>
import {NgApp} from "../../bootstrap";



module views.components.home {
    export class HomeComponent {
        public constructor() {
        }

        public static factory():Function[] {
            return [
                () => new HomeComponent()
            ]
        }

    }

}

NgApp.registerComponents(views.components.home,() => this.app.controller);
```

Here is my GULP task

```
let tsResult = gulp.src('src/**/*.ts').pipe(ts({
    module: 'commonjs',
    sourceMap: true
}));

let taskTs = tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('built/'));
```

This is my error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

The question is: How can I use import like es6 in typescript? What I am missing?

Comment: Try to compile with module: "amd"

Comment: @Amid nope it doesn't helps

Comment: I assume you have a link to system.js on your web page. You can also try compiling with module:system as stated in angular2 quickstart guide.

Comment: I'm doing it with angularjs 1.5

Comment: I have not tried with 1.5. But for 1.4 I had 'amd' as module + reference on main html page to angular.js etc. and it did the trick.

Comment: @Amid do you have a git example?

Comment: Sorry - no. It was a company private project I am not entitled to release on public.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use angular 1.6 and webpack,
it works on my side when i changed the module to **"umd"**

> UMD: Universal Module Definition This has brought about the push for a
>   “universal” pattern that supports both styles (AMD and CommonJS)
>
> reference: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/

pasted here is my tsconfig.json after I changed it, I run $ tsc

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "umd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

then my *"exports is not defined"* error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

[click here](http://Microsoft/TypeScript#6319) "Solved finally" i was also getting same error i changed module:"commonjs" to "module": "es6", because targeting ES5 remove the import/export statements, so these tools cannot remove unused exports.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use import like es6 in typescript? What I am missing?

You need to use a module loader. Here is a sample that uses webpack : https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: sorry mate I use angularjs 1.5 and actually not really familiar with webpack, can I use systemjs with the same abilities to load modules?

Comment: You can. But it is much more bleeding edge (and needless for me as webpack already does everything I need it to)