# TypeScript is adding Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); throwing an error

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs, jspm

I have recently updated typescript at the new version 2.2.1 after this I began to receive this error on the browser:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: "exports is not defined"

I noticed that typescript is adding this line after "use strict" at the began of the .js transpile file when the there is an import statement at the .ts file.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

So I re installed the previous version 2.1.6 and that line disappeared and everything works fine again.

Is this an expected behavior of this new version? How could I go throw this?

By the way I'm using SystemJS with JSPM

Comment: Thanks for this question! I did the same to avoid this exports is not defined problem! Eagerly waiting for the answer. :)

Comment: @AshokMA I'm wondering why the angular 2 developers are not reporting this same issue... It's been a while. weird!

Answer (score 5):

I find the same issue.
[Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined and require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895737/uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined-and-require)

This solution is work for me. I change the setting of "tsconfig.json"

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "umd"
  }
}
```