# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined visual studio 2017

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript2.0

hi I created a project with angularjs 1.6 and typescript 2.6 with visual studio 2017 professional, but from the debug console I get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: export is not defined, looking on the web I found various solutions how to create a tsconfig.json file that I put under main root of the project, but I do not solve the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined and require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895737/uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined-and-require)

Comment: duplicate where?, i have source in github for whatching